# What is the best way to empty a node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a gallery with a long list of thumbnails. To prevent the DOM to be filled up with nodes, I am reusing them. What is the best way to remove the nodes from the DOM (without using a library)?

Using `innerHTML = ""` will parse and create a new empty text node, but looping and removing child will cause reflows?

Comment: `node.innerHTML = ""` does *not* create a new empty node, instead it empties `node`.

Comment: If you are reusing them why are you trying to remove them. Are you trying to replace the thumbnail in a html element and if so just set the `href` attribute on the `img` element.

Comment: I am pooling the nodes for later reuse.

Comment: so innerHTML = "" does not create an empty text node?

Comment: Is this a case of premature optimisation. Is your application slow? Have you measured its performance?

Comment: the application will not refresh, so to avoid memory problems I am trying to keep node creation to a minimum

Comment: @IntoTheVoid: *"the application will not refresh, so to avoid memory problems I am trying to keep node creation to a minimum"* FWIW, I would let the browser worry about memory management until/unless you have a actual, palpable problem to address.

Comment: @IntoTheVoid: *"Using innerHTML = "" will parse and create a new empty text node..."* No, [there's no text node created](http://jsbin.com/ocimin/1). But it does seem to fire up an HTML parser even though the string is blank -- or at least, *something* takes some time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have at least four options:

1. Using `innerHTML = ""` as you've shown in the question. It will make sure the element on which you call it has no child nodes at all, and doesn't create any new nodes. It's [specified](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-innerhtml-mixin) and reliable cross-browser (although [there's an IE bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741528/is-there-a-bug-in-internet-explorer-9-10-with-innerhtml) that may or may not affect your code), and is probably fairly efficient.
2. Using `textContent = ""`, which is also [specified](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent) and reliable cross-browser (IE9+) and, interestingly, IE11 (at least) doesn't seem to have the bug with `textContent` that it has with `innerHTML`. It also has the advantage of not requiring an HTML parser, where of course the string you give `innerHTML` is expected to be HTML. (Browsers may well have an optimization in place for when the string is blank, though.)
3. You could use `removeChild` in a loop, but that involves potentially repeated function calls into the DOM:

   ```
   // assuming elm is the element
   while (elm.firstChild) {
      elm.removeChild(elm.firstChild);
   }
   ```
4. You could *replace* the parent element with a clone omitting the children:

   ```
   // assuming elm is the element
   const clone = elm.cloneNode(false);
   parent.parentElement.replaceChild(clone, elm);
   elm = clone;
   ```

   Note that unlike the others, this will remove any event handlers on the parent element.

If I had to guess, I'd guess that `textContent = ""` would be fastest, at least if there are a **lot** of children. But **performance usually doesn't matter**, it's an extremely rare case where this will be the noticeably slow part of your code. If you run into a situation where it matters, test your actual code usihng each of the options in your target browsers and choose the one that works best.

People love synthetic benchmarks, but **synthetic benchmarks are remarkably unreliable** and sensitive to benchmark assumptions (such as the number of children being removed).

Answer (score 3):

You can also just call [`node.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren#emptying_a_node) and it will empty the node. It's quick, clean, and makes your intention clear.

Comment: this is the c orrect answer, works perfectly for me 

Comment: @CAlonsoCOrtega care to elaborate why this is superior to the accepted solution?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clearNode(node, clone = true) {
  let emptyNode;

  if (clone) {
    emptyNode = node.cloneNode();
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(emptyNode, node);
    node = emptyNode;
  }
  else {
    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    emptyNode = node;
  }

  return emptyNode;
}
```