# Remove child nodes (or elements) or set innerHTML=""?

Tags: javascript, dom

When clearing HTML elements such as select boxes, tables, or lists, is it better/faster to remove the nodes (e.g., `select.options.remove(i)`, `table.deleteRow(i)`) or just empty the innerHTML (e.g., `select.innerHTML = ""`)? Or does it matter?

An example case would be reinitializing a table. A specific select field's value should load different values for a subsequent HTML table. When the select value changes, the table needs to be reinitialized.

Comment: IMO it depends whether you're planning to use them again, if you no longer need them then it would make sense to remove the nodes. I usually clear them instead as they often have an impact on the layout of a page.

Comment: Let's say if you're reinitializing the table, for example, clearing everything, and starting new.

Comment: "Better" in performance terms? I encourage you to create a test on http://jspref.com and discover for yourself.

Comment: @apsillers The point of asking was to find people with experience and insight, not to be lazy. But thanks for the insinuation.

Comment: "Or does it matter" -- in practically all real life situations, no.

Comment: @Juhana based upon Frit's answer/link, it looks like the difference matters.

Comment: @reformed I certainly didn't mean to insinuate any such thing -- performance questions are customarily greeted with a link to jsperf, since performance questions can usually be answered objectively by testing. Not everyone knows about jsperf (did you?); my intention was merely to introduce the tool to you. Furthermore, I didn't mean to suggest your question was without merit: I specifically said "better in performance terms" to clarify that jsperf could answer that question for you; other metrics of "better" (most idiomatic in JS, most readable) are quite appropriate for a Q&A site like SO.

Comment: @apsillers No I did not know about that, but it seems like a handy resource. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @reformed Let's assume *very generously* that a user notices if removing an element takes 100ms. According to Frits's link, on my computer, in 100ms you can perform `innerHTML = ''` about 45,000 times. In what real life situation do you need to remove the contents of 45,000 elements?

Comment: @reformed Oh, one other thing, for the future, now that you know about jsperf: when asking a performance question, it's customary to run a test (or find a test someone else made) in advance and then ask "why?" about the results. It's true that raw performance numbers can be obtained easily, but "why?" is much harder to answer, and is an appropriate reason to ask for experienced assistance. Again, I don't mean to criticize; I'm just trying to help you arm yourself with as many problem-solving tools as possible.

Comment: @apsillers thank you, I appreciate the consideration

Comment: @Juhana, point taken. However, according to Christophe's answer, it matters quite significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a new test that isn't broken.

http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild/67

It's not perfect either since part of the sample setup is part of the test so this might skew the results.

This gives that `innerHTML` is faster but I don't know by how much.

Comment: `.innerHTML = ""` should realize that it only needs to clear the element content. And it clears the content in native code, whereas the while loop constantly crosses js/dom boundary. So we should expect it to be faster. We could verify this from e.g. webkit source.

Comment: It does create a fragment from the "html" but when attempting to insert the fragment, there is [fast path to remove all children](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/editing/markup.cpp#L1086)

Answer (score 5):

[In IE you cannot set the innerHTML of a select element](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228). So for a cross-browser solution the only way is to add/remove child nodes.

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1:-**
**Run  on 1000 Child DOM Element to Remove.**

***Which one is Faster?***

1. Remove Child (5,676,264 ops/sec ±1.46%) --> **Faster**
2. innerHTML = "" (4,359,867 ops/sec ±1.46%) --> **Slower**

**Case 2:-**
**Which one is able to remove event handler of child Nodes?**

1. Remove Child --> **Able to remove event handler**
2. innerHTML = "" --> **Not able to remove event handler**

**Result:-**

**Seems It's better to used Remove Child for removing any child nodes.**

Ref:-
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6910/0/innerhtml-vs-removechild-vs-remove

https://rusingh.com/javascript-benchmark-removechild-vs-innerhtml/

Answer (score 2):

Per this conversation here: [What is the best way to empty an node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-an-node-in-javascript)

It appears that the `while (elm.firstChild) {elm.removeChild(elm.firstChild);}` approach got the the best results across browsers in [this test](http://jsperf.com/empty-an-element/4).

*(Would have put this as a comment instead of an answer, but the comments are coming in awful fast, so I didn't want it to get lost.)*

Comment: I suppose the test is dependent on the distribution of the nodes. Deep trees makes innerHTML slower.