# Best way to remove children from a parent element?

Tags: javascript

I am working with dinamically created JavaScript elements. All of the elements are appended to the same div, but from time to time I need to empty the div and add new elements.

In a previous project I used a method where I added every generated element's `ID` to an array, and when I had to remove them I run the following algorith:

```
for (var a = IDArray.length-1; a>=0; a--){
    var element = document.getElementById(IDArray[a]);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    IDArray.splice(a,1);
}
```

It worked perfectly, but I started to think: I am appending to- and remove from a div, which has an `innerHTML` value. So I could just use the following line to empty the div:

```
document.getElementById("parentDiv").innerHTML = "";
```

I tried it, and they both achieved the same thing, at least it looked like it.

My question is: is using the innerHTML method has any consequences that could cause problems with the usability of the site? Or is it simply a shorter, thus more effective way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the second example is fine.

From my experience, very novice JavaScript coders use innerHTML too much. But, adept JavaScript coders probably don't use it often enough.

On the one hand, it's a simple convenience method - and you do have to think of it more like a method than a property. It shouldn't be overused for just adding individual nodes to an element.

But, if you're making a cursory change to an element's entire content, and it's very easy to create/retrieve some HTML representation of that, then it's fine to use; keep in mind that it's written in the browser's native code (C++) so it may run faster than whatever loop you've assembled.

To avoid use of IDs, keep in mind you can retrieve an element's children with "elem.children", which returns an array-like (not capital-A Array) structure. You can also re-find elements quickly if you give them all a shared class. In my own projects, I only give an element an ID if I know for certain there will only be one of them in the entire document; and I never assign IDs numerically.

Answer (score 5):

There are a fair number of discussions on this. E.g: [What is the best way to empty an node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084941/remove-child-nodes-or-elements-or-set-innerhtml).

The fastest method, especially on deeply nested elements, appears to be:

```
while(element.firstChild){
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, setting innerHTML to "" is a perfectly good solution for removing elements. In fact, if you kept a reference to the old elements in an array, you'd have to clean up the array to allow them to be garbage collected.

Of course, if you do need the references for another reason, don't forget to see that those references (or the objects containing them) are removed when you remove the elements from the DOM.

Cleaning children without using innerHTML doesn't really require those references though. You can get away with:

```
while(parent.firstChild) parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no doubt number of ways to do so, but in case you have the reference to the child element (A variable holding the element reference) than you can simply do:

```
myChildNode.parentNode.removeChild(myChildNode);
```

Otherwise *innerHtml* also has no consequences.