# Assignment in loop predicate, are parentheses needed?

Tags: javascript, loops, variable-assignment, predicates

Here's a function in JavaScript that replaces the children of a node

```
var app = {};
app.replaceChildren = function (node, childrenReplacementNode) {
    var child;
    while (child = node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(child);
    }
    node.appendChild(childrenReplacementNode);
};
```

Are there any JS implementations that require the predicate to be written as

`((child = node.firstChild))`?

Comment: Well, no. The parens accept any expression, and return its result, so they're equivalent. However, linters may complain about an assignment in that position. A common syntax that linters accept is to use the extra parens around the assignment in order to let it know that you do intend the assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: ...here's the [jsHint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#boss) that show the parens being used to silence the warning. So if your question is motivated by some code that you saw, that's likely the reason for it.

Comment: You may find this question and its answers interesting, re your code for emptying out an element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-an-node-in-javascript

Comment: @squint: Oooh, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No, extra parens are never required there by JavaScript, and if present they serve no purpose at a language level.

An engine would have to be radically broken to get that wrong. The result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned (that's why `a = b = foo()` works), and the expression in a `while` loop's parens is evaluated and then the resulting value coerced to boolean to determine whether the loop should continue. Any engine doing either of those wrong (or adding a code-breaking lint-style error) wouldn't fare well in the wild.