# Remove <div> elements created by Javascript by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

My code atm looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Oppgave 2</title>

<style type="text/css">
div{
 width: 100px; 
 height: 100px;
 background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<label>
 <ul>
  <li>Antall <input id="numberFigInput" type="text"></li>
 </ul>
</label>

<input id="genFigBtn" type="button" value="Generate">
<input id="removeFigBtn" type="button" value="Remove All">

<section id="myFigures"></section>

<script>

var numberFig, genFigBtn, myFigures;

function init(){
 numberFigInput = document.getElementById("numberFigInput");
 myFigures = document.getElementById("myFigures");

 genFigBtn = document.getElementById("genFigBtn");
 removeFigBtn = document.getElementById("removeFigBtn");

 genFigBtn.onclick = genFigures;
 removeFigBtn.onclick = removeFigures;
}

function genFigures(){
 var numberFig = numberFigInput.value;

 if (numberFig > 0, numberFig < 1001){
  for(var amount = 0; amount < numberFig; amount++){
   myFigures.innerHTML += "<div></div>"
  }
 }else{
  alert("You have to input an integer over 0, but not over 1000!");
 }
}
function removeFigures(){
 
}
init();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

So what I want, is for the remove-button to remove the divs that im creating. Ive been googling around and have tried alot of different codes, cant seem to get it to work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific situation, you have two basic choices:

1. Just set `innerHTML` on the element to `""`:

   ```
   myFigures.innerHTML = "";
   ```

   It's slower than some alternatives, but you're not doing this in a tight loop, and it's easy.
2. Use a loop with `removeChild`:

   ```
   while (myFigures.firstChild) {
       myFigures.removeChild(myFigures.firstChild);
   }
   ```

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798847/157247) for information comparing the two techniques.

Here's that first option in context:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Oppgave 2</title>

<style type="text/css">
div{
 width: 100px; 
 height: 100px;
 background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<label>
 <ul>
  <li>Antall <input id="numberFigInput" type="text"></li>
 </ul>
</label>

<input id="genFigBtn" type="button" value="Generate">
<input id="removeFigBtn" type="button" value="Remove All">

<section id="myFigures"></section>

<script>

var numberFig, genFigBtn, myFigures;

function init(){
 numberFigInput = document.getElementById("numberFigInput");
 myFigures = document.getElementById("myFigures");

 genFigBtn = document.getElementById("genFigBtn");
 removeFigBtn = document.getElementById("removeFigBtn");

 genFigBtn.onclick = genFigures;
 removeFigBtn.onclick = removeFigures;
}

function genFigures(){
 var numberFig = numberFigInput.value;

 if (numberFig > 0, numberFig < 1001){
  for(var amount = 0; amount < numberFig; amount++){
   myFigures.innerHTML += "<div></div>"
  }
 }else{
  alert("You have to input an integer over 0, but not over 1000!");
 }
}
function removeFigures(){
    myFigures.innerHTML = "";
}
init();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like T.J. Crowder said,

```
myFigures.innerHTML = "";
```

would work.  However, that assumes that myFigures is empty when your DOM is initially loaded.  If that is NOT the case, you need to add a class to the div when you create it.
AddDiv function:

```
function genFigures(){
    var numberFig = numberFigInput.value;

    if (numberFig > 0, numberFig < 1001){
        for(var amount = 0; amount < numberFig; amount++){
            myFigures.innerHTML += "<div class='AddedDiv'></div>"
        }
    }else{
        alert("You have to input an integer over 0, but not over 1000!");
    }
}
```

To remove them:

```
$(".AddedDiv").each(function(){
    $(this).parentNode.removeChild($(this));
});
```

Comment: I think if you were going to do this, you'd be much better off with a class and `querySelectorAll`. The you wouldn't need the `AddedDivs` array at all.

Comment: Wow - how did I miss that?