# Is there a bug in Internet Explorer 9/10 with innerHTML=""?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I often use the following code to clear the content of an element :

```
div.innerHTML = "";
```

But I found a stange behaviour on Internet Explorer. It seems that all children of the div get their own children removed too! If I keep a reference to a child of the div above, after doing `div.innerHTML = "";`, the child's text node is no longer in the child.

The following code is the proof of this behaviour (http://jsfiddle.net/Laudp273/):

```
function createText() {
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.textContent = "Hello World!";
    return e;
}

var mrk = document.createElement("div");
mrk.appendChild(createText());
mrk.style.border = "4px solid yellow";

var container = null;

function addDiv() {
    if (container) {
        container.innerHTML = "";
    }
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.appendChild(mrk);
    container = e;
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}

var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "Add marker";
btn.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() {
        addDiv();
    },
    false
);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

If you click on the "Add Marker" button twice, you will see an empty yellow rectangle instead of one with the texte "Hello wordl!".

Is this a bug or a specification not used by Firefox nor Google Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's very interesting behavior, and happens on IE8 and IE11 as well. Here's a rather simpler test/proof:

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This disappears on IE"));

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(span);
snippet.log("[before] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
div.innerHTML = "";
snippet.log("[after] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

After setting the `div`'s `innerHTML` to `""`, the `span` we kept a reference to loses its child text node on IE, and not on other browsers.

[We're not the only ones to notice this and find it, um, inappropriate.](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/818214/innerhtml-destroys-descendants-text-nodes-and-dismantles-descendant-elements-hierarchy)

It doesn't have to be `""`, either, any new content causes the bug:

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This disappears on IE"));

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(span);
snippet.log("[before] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
div.innerHTML = "New content"; // <== Not ""
snippet.log("[after] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

[What little we have in the way of a spec for `innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#attributes) is quite vague on what should happen to the old content, but surely this is wrong, even if Microsoft *did* invent `innerHTML`.

Whereas removing the nodes via `removeNode` doesn't cause this behavior:

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This disappears on IE"));

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(span);
snippet.log("[before] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
while (div.firstChild) {
  div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
snippet.log("[after] span's childNodes.length: " + span.childNodes.length);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

***sigh***

Comment: I agree. Microsoft's interpretation is more than vague. That's why I do not use `div.innerHTML = ""` anymore. I use `removeChild` on each childnode, but I'm not sure this is faster.

Comment: @Tolokoban: It is, actually -- dramatically so. I have an answer kicking around somewhere with performance tests, and (to my surprise at the time) `removeChild` was faster than setting `innerHTML` to `""`. *Edit*: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13798847/157247

Comment: The linked answer has already been updated. But to clarify here as well, using `innerHTML` is faster.

Comment: @MichaelBest: Yes indeed (thanks again for pointing out the earlier error). Not that it's likely to matter. :-)