# Javascript single page application strange behavior in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript single page application with lots of code in it.

The main idea is that my app creates canvases and draws in them all kinds of stuff
based on all kinds of data.

Each canvas is within a div container. Each div container also contains a paragraph next to the canvas.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11 something strange happens:

The container divs are empty after they are appended to the main document.
And I have no idea why.

Another strange thing is that if I break the app by inserting the following code  after the section where the container divs are appended, then the canvases and the paragraphs are also appended and visible two:

```
var foo = some_var; //where some_var is undefined
```

So, the code is huge, but here is a sample, just to make an idea:

A.js file:

```
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("some text");
var div = document.createElement("div");
paragraph.appendChild(textnode);
div.appendChild(paragraph);
div.appendChild(canvas);

someOBJ.html = div;
```

B.js file:

```
var parent2 = document.getElementById(parentId);
parent2.innerHTML = "";
parent2.style.width = '100%';

//someOBJs is an array of someOBJ from the A.js file
for(var i = 0; i < someOBJs.length; i++){
        parent2.appendChild(someOBJs[i].html);
}
```

If I insert here the breaking code (using something that is undefined) that I mentioned above then the canvases and paragraphs are appended, else only the div containers (someOBJs[i].html) are appended

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: @mplungjan if I do not insert the breaking code then no errors are shown

Comment: i see you're appending `canvas`, but where is that defined?  I think we're missing some of the code.

Comment: @ps2goat the canvas is defined in another file.

Comment: you should put the minimum details of that file in this question, otherwise this is of no help to people in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be related to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741528/is-there-a-bug-in-internet-explorer-9-10-with-innerhtml) regarding `innerHTML = ""` in IE. Try using removeChild to empty the div:

```
while (parent2.lastChild) 
  elm.removeChild(parent2.lastChild);
```

On the other hand, as the cause might performance-related: using a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) you can attach all nodes to the DOM at once instead of one-by-one:

```
var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < someOBJs.length; i++){
   elements.appendChild(someOBJs[i].html);
}
parent2.appendChild(elements);
```