# Javascript - IE11 - void results with querySelectAll()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, selectors-api

I have an issue with a simple js function on IE (11 and lower). When I use document.querySelector('#id').querySelectorAll('option') where #id is linked to a  element, it return an array of options, but "void" like

```
<option id="id"></options>
```

my very simple JS :

```
var projectsList = document.querySelector('#taskproject').querySelectorAll('option');
console.dirxml(projectsList);
```

and my HTML code (an exemple) :

```
<select id="taskproject" name="newproject">
    <option id="1">Project1</option>
    <option id="2">Project2</option>
    [...]
    <option id="99">Project99</option>
</select>
```

This will return, with the console.dirxml function in the IE11 console

```
<NodeList lenght="99">
    <option id="1"></option>
    [....]
    <option id="99"></option>
</NodeList>
```

This works on chrome, the text inside options is written on the console.
Thanks for your help!

---

Edit with runnable example

```js
var projectsList = document.querySelector('#taskproject').querySelectorAll('option');

  function giveSelection(appId)
  {
      var appSelector = document.querySelector('#taskapp');
      var projectSelector = document.querySelector('#taskproject');
      projectSelector.innerHTML = '';
      if(projectSelector != null)
      {
        for(var i=0; i<projectsList.length; i++)
        {
          if(projectsList[i].id.split('_')[1] === appId)
          {
            projectSelector.appendChild(projectsList[i]);
          } 
        }
      }      
  }
```

```html
<select id="taskapp" name="new_app_id" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
    <option value="55" >Proj1</option>
    <option value="33" >Proj2</option>
    <option value="62" >Proj3</option>
    <option value="69" >Proj4</option>
</select>

<select id="taskproject" name="new_project_id">
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="239" >Proj1 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="273" >Proj1 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="289" >Proj1 - c</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_33" value="106" >Proj2 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_33" value="105" >Proj2 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_62" value="263" >Proj3 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_62" value="264" >Proj3 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_69" value="285" >Proj4 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_69" value="286" >Proj4 - b</option>
</select>
```

Here, if I choose Proj2 on first select, it will show me only Proj2 - a and Proj2 - b on the second select (on chrome). On IE11, it will show me 2 "options" with no text inside.

Comment: Every browser will have custom representation in console. Can you specify what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I use the var projectsList to "send" options to an other select, and in my case, options exist, but there is no text in them. It's not only an issue with the console.dirxml, it really "void" inside option elements!

Comment: Side note: `document.querySelector('#taskproject').querySelectorAll('option')` can more simply be written `document.querySelectorAll('#taskproject option')`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, my first post here, and no internet connexion on my work computer (not so easy to write code...). I edit my post. My probleme is just when I click on an option in the first select, it give me the linked options in the second on chrome, but on IE, options on the 2nd select are void. (and very sorry for my english...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops so sorry, it's done now... I don't know if it's work, the website is forbidden on my localnetwork...

Comment: @MathieuLanglais: Yup! It works, and it demonstrates the problem occurring in IE11 (and not occurring in Chrome).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741528/is-there-a-bug-in-internet-explorer-9-10-with-innerhtml (Note: A question being a duplicate does not mean it's a bad question. It just means that the other question's answers answer this question as well. Sometimes, until you know the answer, you don't know that it's a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IE has a very strange behavior when you set `innerHTML`. It removes the text nodes of the elements it's removing. This is non-standard, and arguably a bug. (In fact, I seem to recall reporting it as a bug at one point.)

You can work around it by not using `innerHTML = ''` to clear the `select`, but instead using `removeChild`:

```js
var projectsList = document.querySelector('#taskproject').querySelectorAll('option');

function giveSelection(appId)
{
    var appSelector = document.querySelector('#taskapp');
    var projectSelector = document.querySelector('#taskproject');
    if(projectSelector != null)
    {
      // Not this: projectSelector.innerHTML = '';
      while (projectSelector.firstChild) {
        projectSelector.removeChild(projectSelector.firstChild);
      }
      for(var i=0; i<projectsList.length; i++)
      {
        if(projectsList[i].id.split('_')[1] === appId)
        {
          projectSelector.appendChild(projectsList[i]);
        } 
      }
    }      
}
```

```html
<select id="taskapp" name="new_app_id" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
    <option value="55" >Proj1</option>
    <option value="33" >Proj2</option>
    <option value="62" >Proj3</option>
    <option value="69" >Proj4</option>
</select>

<select id="taskproject" name="new_project_id">
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="239" >Proj1 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="273" >Proj1 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_55" value="289" >Proj1 - c</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_33" value="106" >Proj2 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_33" value="105" >Proj2 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_62" value="263" >Proj3 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_62" value="264" >Proj3 - b</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_69" value="285" >Proj4 - a</option>
    <option id="appWithProject_69" value="286" >Proj4 - b</option>
</select>
```

---

Side note: You also had the `innerHTML` thing *before* the `if (projectSelector != null)` check. I've put it inside that `if`'s body instead.