# Unexpected output while using JavaScript for loop in the context of removing Child Nodes

Tags: javascript

Given below are my HTML and two JavaScript looping constructs (`for` and `while`). When executed, the `while` loop works as expected, but the `for` loop doesn't seem to get executed in one like the `while` loop is. The `for` loop code has to be re-run till all the child nodes are removed.

Using a `for` loop:

```js
var article = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
for (var i = 0; i < article.childNodes.length; i++) {
  article.removeChild(article.childNodes[i]); //even you can replace i with 0 (zero)
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>An Introduction to JavaScript</h1>
  <p>Removing Elements</p>
</header>

<article>

  <p id="p1">My <strong>first</strong> paragraph.</p>

  <p id="p2">My <strong>second</strong> paragraph.</p>

</article>
```

Using a `while` loop:

```js
var article = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
while (article.childNodes.length) {
 article.removeChild(article.childNodes[0])
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>An Introduction to JavaScript</h1>
  <p>Removing Elements</p>
</header>

<article>

  <p id="p1">My <strong>first</strong> paragraph.</p>

  <p id="p2">My <strong>second</strong> paragraph.</p>

</article>
```

What's going on with the `for` loop here?

Comment: after deleting a node (p) tag, the next node's index become `previous_index -1`. and when all nodes are deleted,  the childNodes[0] returns error, because there is no child node with index 0. 

in for-loop use, `article.remove(article.childNodes[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove an entry from the beginning of the `childNodes` collection, the collection immediately adjusts for the fact that child is no longer there, so the element that was at index 1 is now at index 0, index 2 moved to index 1, etc. `length` also updates dynamically, as you'd expect.

Since you're increasing `i` as you go, you end up skipping every other element: You remove 0, which moves the others down; then you remove 1, which moves the others down, etc. It happens that in your example, you end up removing the text nodes and not the elements. Here's what happens:

To start with, you have this inside your `article` element:

```
0: Text node containing whitespace
1: `p` element
2: Text node with whitespace
3: `p` element
4: Text node with whitespace
```

The loop with `i == 0` removes the first one, leaving us with:

```
0: `p` element
1: Text node with whitespace
2: `p` element
3: Text node with whitespace
```

...and `i` is now `1`. Then the next iteration removes the node at index 1, leaving is with:

```
0: `p` element
1: `p` element
2: Text node with whitespace
```

...and `i` is now `2`. Then the next iteration removes the node at index 2:

```
0: `p` element
1: `p` element
```

...and `i` is now `3`, `length` is now `2`, and the loop stops.

To use the `for` loop, loop *backward*

```
for (var i = article.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    article.removeChild(article.childNodes[i]);
}
```

```js
var article = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
for (var i = article.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  article.removeChild(article.childNodes[i]);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>An Introduction to JavaScript</h1>
  <p>Removing Elements</p>
</header>

<article>

  <p id="p1">My <strong>first</strong> paragraph.</p>

  <p id="p2">My <strong>second</strong> paragraph.</p>

</article>
```

See also: [*What is the best way to empty an node in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-an-node-in-javascript) and its answers.

Comment: Thank you so much! i just missed the simple stuff out of oversight!! Thank you , i appreciate you :)