# Javascript, after eventhandler back to default (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom, eventhandler

Hello sorry for maybe a stupid question but i can't seem to find a easy solution.

The meaning of my exercise is to put 3 thumbnails on my website, but when I move over the images they need to expand in size (so i have a thumbnail version of the picture and the normal size). The normal size picture has to be on the

```
<p id="groot"></p>
```

This do work correctly, the only problem is that the pictures keep showing up when i move over it. So when I move out of the thumbnail the picture need to dissapear. Is there a function or something that get the site to the original state or any solution? Thanks in advance. I hope I explained it clearly.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if you have tips for a complete noob :)

This is the body of my  HTML code:

```
<body> 
<p><img  id="foto1" src="images/thumb-bones.jpg" alt="bones"/>
<img src="images/thumb-castle.jpg" alt="castle"/>
<img src="images/thumb-mentalist.jpg" alt="mentalist"/>
</p> 

<p id="groot"></p>
</body>
```

This is the JS code:

```
addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
    let foto1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", actie, false);
    let foto2 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].addEventListener("mouseover", actie2, false);
    let foto3 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[2].addEventListener("mouseover", actie3, false);
    foto1.addEventListener("click", uit, false);
}


function actie(event) {
    let plaats = document.getElementById("groot");
    let element = document.createElement("img");
    element.src = 'images/image-bones.jpg';
    plaats.appendChild(element);

}


function actie2(event) {
    let plaats = document.getElementById("groot");
    let element = document.createElement("img");
    element.src = 'images/image-castle.jpg';
    plaats.appendChild(element);

}

function actie3(event) {
    let plaats = document.getElementById("groot");
    let element = document.createElement("img");
    element.src = 'images/image-mentalist.jpg';
    plaats.appendChild(element);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mouseout` handler and, in the handler, remove all children from that element. An easy way to do that is to assign `""` to `innerHTML`. So for instance:

```
function actie_off(event) {
    document.getElementById("groot").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Hook that up to all three thumbnails.

If you don't want to use `innerHTML`, [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-a-node-in-javascript) give alternatives.

---

You might consider [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) instead of [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout). Probably doesn't make much difference here, it's just that `mouseover` repeats as the mouse moves across the thumbnails, and the bubbling of `mouseout` can be confusing with nested elements (not currently relevant for you). See the links for details.

---

Another thing to consider is to store the fullsize image URL on the thumbnail `img` elements as a `data-*` URI, like this:

```
<img id="foto1" src="images/thumb-bones.jpg" alt="bones" data-fullsize="images/image-bones.jpg"/>
```

Then you can use a single handler for all of your `img` elements instead of three separate ones:

```
function actie(event) {
    let plaats = document.getElementById("groot");
    let element = document.createElement("img");
    element.src = this.getAttribute("data-fullsize"); // Getting the fullsize URL
                                                      // from the image the event
                                                      // relates to
    plaats.appendChild(element);
}
```