# How do you remove tags before and after a special tag in html code using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to remove all tags in a div with the class of 'item' with Javascript with the exception of one tag, the `<b>` tag.

This is what my HTML document looks like, (My sample code):

```
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sample-href1">
            <div class="result-image">
                <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h4>1.
            <a href="sample-href2" title="sample-title2">
                <b> goal tag1 (i need just this tag) </b>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <span class="feature">test</span>
        <div class="compact">
            </br>
            <a href="test12" title="test12"> test12 </a>
            <br>
            <b> some text </b>
            <a href="test123" title="test123"> test123 </a> -
            <a href="test147" title="test147" > test147 </a>
            </br>
            <b>11</b>
            another some text
            </br>
        </div>
        <a href="test159" title="test159" class="download"> test </a>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sample-href1968">
            <div class="result-image">
                <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test418</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <h4>2.
            <a href="sample-href215" title="sample-title215">
                <b> goal tag2 (i need just this tag) </b>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <span class="feature">test23</span>
        <div class="compact">
            </br>
            <a href="test12234" title="test12234"> test12234 </a>
            <br>
            <b> some text </b>
            <a href="test12233" title="test12233"> test12233 </a> -
            <a href="test14657" title="test14657" > test14657 </a>
            </br>
            <b>16</b>
            another some text
            </br>
        </div>
        <a href="test15912" title="test15912" class="download"> test </a>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    ... (and so on (<div class=item> ... </div>))
```

i need just to this tag `<b> goad tag(1, 2, ...) (i need just this tag) </b>`, i want to remove all tags before and after it in this tag `<div class=item> ... </div>` with javascript.

note : i have many div (`<div class=item> ... </div>`) in a source file(test.html) and i want to when i loaded page i just have something like this :

```
<div class=item>
   <b> goal tag1 (i need just this tag) </b>
</div>
<div class=item>
   <b> goal tag1 (i need just this tag) </b>
</div>
...
```

I am extremely new to Javascript, Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it by looping through the `div.item` elements, finding the `b` element within, removing all elements from the `div`, then adding the `b` back:

```
// Find all the div.item elements
document.querySelectorAll("div.item").forEach(function(div) {
  // Find the first `b` element with the desired matching text
  var b = Array.prototype.find.call(
    div.querySelectorAll("b"),
    function(b) {
      return b.textContent.indexOf("goal tag") !== -1;
    }
  );
  // Remove all children from the div
  while (div.lastChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
  }
  // If we found the relevant `b` element, add it back
  if (b) {
    div.appendChild(b);
  }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.item").forEach(function(div) {
  var b = Array.prototype.find.call(
    div.querySelectorAll("b"),
    function(b) {
      return b.textContent.indexOf("goal tag") !== -1;
    }
  );
  while (div.lastChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
  }
  if (b) {
    div.appendChild(b);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="sample-href1">
    <div class="result-image">
      <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <h4>1.
    <a href="sample-href2" title="sample-title2">
      <b> goal tag1 (i need just this tag) </b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <span class="feature">test</span>
  <div class="compact">
    <a href="test12" title="test12"> test12 </a>
    <br>
    <b> some text </b>
    <a href="test123" title="test123"> test123 </a> -
    <a href="test147" title="test147"> test147 </a>
    <b>11</b> another some text
  </div>
  <a href="test159" title="test159" class="download"> test </a>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="sample-href1968">
    <div class="result-image">
      <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test418</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <h4>2.
    <a href="sample-href215" title="sample-title215">
      <b> goal tag2 (i need just this tag) </b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <span class="feature">test23</span>
  <div class="compact">
    </br>
    <a href="test12234" title="test12234"> test12234 </a>
    <br>
    <b> some text </b>
    <a href="test12233" title="test12233"> test12233 </a> -
    <a href="test14657" title="test14657"> test14657 </a>
    <b>16</b> another some text
  </div>
  <a href="test15912" title="test15912" class="download"> test </a>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Or with ES2015+:

```
// Find all the div.item elements
for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("div.item")) {
  // Find the first `b` element with the desired matching text
  const b = [...div.querySelectorAll("b")].find(b => b.textContent.includes("goal tag"));
  // Remove all children from the div
  while (div.lastChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
  }
  // If we found the relevant `b` element, add it back
  if (b) {
    div.appendChild(b);
  }
});
```

---

Note that `forEach` on the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` is relatively new; [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) has a polyfill you can use for older browsers (including IE8 and up).

That loop to remove the content of the `div.item` is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-a-node-in-javascript) and its answers (including [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798847/157247)).

---

See also [Krzysztof Janiszewski's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483407/157247) doing a round-trip through markup, which is quite reasonable if you know there aren't event handlers on the `b` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to do it. You just take html of the tag you want to leave and replace html of `<div class="item">` with this html.

**EDIT**

I altered a little bit code so that the `b` tag that stays is actually the one you want and not just the first one in `<div class="item">`

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

function hasGoal(el) {
  return el.innerHTML.indexOf("goal tag") !== -1;
}

for (var item of items) {
  var b = Array.from(item.getElementsByTagName("b")).filter(hasGoal)[0];
  item.innerHTML = b.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="sample-href1">
    <div class="result-image">
      <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <h4>1.
    <a href="sample-href2" title="sample-title2">
      <b> some text </b>
      <b> goal tag1 (i need just this tag) </b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <span class="feature">test</span>
  <div class="compact">
    <br>
    <a href="test12" title="test12"> test12 </a>
    <br>
    <b> some text </b>
    <a href="test123" title="test123"> test123 </a> -
    <a href="test147" title="test147"> test147 </a>
    <br>
    <b>11</b> another some text
    <br>
  </div>
  <a href="test159" title="test159" class="download"> test </a>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="sample-href1968">
    <div class="result-image">
      <h5 class="result-cat cat-conf wn">test418</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <h4>2.
    <a href="sample-href215" title="sample-title215">
      <b> goal tag2 (i need just this tag) </b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <span class="feature">test23</span>
  <div class="compact">
    <br>
    <a href="test12234" title="test12234"> test12234 </a>
    <br>
    <b> some text </b>
    <a href="test12233" title="test12233"> test12233 </a> -
    <a href="test14657" title="test14657"> test14657 </a>
    <br>
    <b>16</b> another some text
    <br>
  </div>
  <a href="test15912" title="test15912" class="download"> test </a>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a bad approach if we know there aren't event handlers on the `b` elements (since this would remove them). But I'd use `querySelectorAll("div.item")` rather than `getElementsByClassName`, since there may well be other elements with the `item` class, and `querySelectorAll` is better-supported than `getElementsByClassName` (though that's only relevant for obsolete browsers like IE8).

Comment: And there are other, unrelated `b` elements, so you can't just grab the first one. (Also possibly the OP could tell us that those won't be in `div.item.`)

Answer (score 1):

First, find every `class=item` element:

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
```

Then, it seems like you want to extract the `<b>` tag inside the `<h4>`. So make sure to extract the correct `<b>` tag for each `item` element and replace all the content with only that element:

```js
items.forEach(item => {
  const title = item.querySelector('h4 b');
  item.innerHTML = '';
  item.appendChild(title);
});
```

Comment: And if there are other elements with the `item` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = $(".item h4 a b");
$("body").html("");
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    $("body").append("<h6>"+$(result[i]).text()+"</h6>");
}
```

i test this and its worked