# Clearing all children of unordered list to then refresh the List

Tags: javascript, promise

So, I'm just learning JavaScript. Was learning about HTTP Requests.

I'm using a *fetchPosts()* function which fetches posts for me and I'm appending each post as a child to my unorderedList. I also have a fetch button which fetches all posts for me and then I display them on my screen. Each time I press the fetch button it would append all the posts again as children of my unordered list. So, I tried clearing my unordered list children using the *clearList()* function.

```
const listElement = document.querySelector('.posts');

function clearList() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    while (listElement.firstChild) {
      listElement.removeChild(listElement.firstChild);
    }
    resolve();
  });
  return promise;
}
```

And then fetching posts using addEventListener on fetchButton.

```
fetchButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  await clearList();
  fetchPosts();
});
```

Is it necessary to promisify this while loop and await this and then fetchPosts() because, as per my understanding this while loop might take some time if there are thousands of posts, to clear all children of my unordered list? Or is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to promisify this while loop and await this and then fetchPosts() because, as per my understanding this while loop might take some time if there are thousands of posts, to clear all children of my unordered list?

No, not at all. You'd use a promise to report the completion of an **asynchronous** process, but clearing out those DOM nodes isn't asynchronous. It's synchronous.

> Or is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Yes: Removing the promise. :-) There are various other suggestions (**all** of which you should double-check, it's been years and browsers have moved on) in the answers to [*What is the best way to empty a node in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798796/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-a-node-in-javascript).

Comment: Note: I see I posted the accepted answer there in 2012. The tests it links to have disappeared and it doesn't mention `textContent`. So I'll update it...

Comment: would setting innerHTML = "" clear the eventListeners of the child nodes of my the list?

Comment: @SarthakMalik - I've updated that other answer now. :-) Happy coding!